# Detail of acceptance criteria in user story

Tags: scrum

I have the following example for a user story with acceptance criteria.

I would like to know if I am allowed to describe how the GUI must be changed to support the new feature. How much detail can acceptance criteria have?

This is my example:

**User Story:**

As forum administrator I will connect persons in groups, so that people can get organized.

**Acceptance Criteria:**

1. The creation of a person group happens below a person group pool (person group pool is an object also visually available in the current software system)
2. The creation happens with a context menu of the persongroup pool. Below the pool one can create new groups.
3. A person group contains: person group-ID, description, remark

May that be relevant an right acceptance criteria? Because I describe how you can create a new group by opening a context menu.

Comment: The crowd at [Project Management Stack Exchange](http://pm.stackexchange.com/) can also help you, if you don't get satisfactory responses here.

Answer (score 3):

Acceptance criteria needs to have enough detail to be accurate. The developer should be able to look at the acceptance criteria and answer the question "am I done?" and not have to worry that the product owner will come back to them and say "you forgot feature X".

Strictly speaking, anything that is *not* mentioned in the acceptance criteria is optional.

In your case, you wrote "May that be relevant an right acceptance criteria? Because I describe how you can create a new group by opening a context menu." If having it implemented with a context menu is important and will be used to judge if the feature is complete or not, the context menu must be part of the acceptance criteria.